# Give string when function criteria is not met in VBA

Tags: string, vba, function, variables, double

I'm attempting to write a function that will terminate if certain criteria are not met. I declare my function as double and if the conditions aren't met, then I hope to return a string. Right now I have the following.

```
Function answer(list As range) As Double

answer = (Evaluate("Sum(COUNTIF(" & list.Address & ",{""L"",""R"",""PD"",""D"",""P"",""S""}))") = list.Cells.Count)

    If answer = False Then
        answer = "Not Valid. Function Terminated"
        Exit Function
    End If

'If conditions are met then function will perform calculations (example output: 1000.23)
answer = 1000.23

End Function
```

One potential solution - I could declare function answer as string and replace the last lines of code

```
dim temp_answer as double
answer = str(temp_answer)
```

That way if the conditions aren't met then I can still get an answer of "Not Valid. Function Terminated"

My main question though, is there a way to keep function answer as double and return string if conditions aren't met?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why as `Double` ? I understand as `String`, maybe `Boolean` , even `Integer` , why do you need `Double` here ? what is the calling procedure doing with this result ?

Comment: The longer version of code requires a double value. Basically what I was trying to accomplish is to first look at the the input (list as range) and if it has values not equal to "L", or "R", or "PD" etc. then the function will terminate. Otherwise it will continue on and perform calculations.

Comment: You can declare the function as returning `Variant` so you can return any type you want.

Comment: If I need to use this function for hundreds of cells, I feel that Variant might impact speed or might that not be the case? Perhaps if I declare a temp_answer as double and make answer = temp_answer once the calculations are complete, then It wouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: Yes, this is a sound idea. Calculate a temporary double and return a variant. Returning a Variant wont slow down because Excel's values in the cells are precisely of type `Variant`.

Comment: another option, you can set a **"Flag"** value , like `If answer = False Then`, next line `answer = -10000` , then in the calling procedure you know that if the result you got is -10000 then it was actually false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed some of our suggestions we talked about yesterday and came up with the following solution.

```
            Function answer(list As range) As Variant

                answer = (Evaluate("Sum(COUNTIF(" & list.Address & ",{""L"",""R"",""PD"",""D"",""P"",""S""}))") = list.Cells.Count)
                    If answer = False Then
                        answer = "ERROR"
                        Exit Function
                    End If

                'Runs rest of code then gives some answer (example output: 1000.83)
                Dim temp_answer As Double
                temp_answer = 1000.83
                answer = temp_answer

            End Function
```